# OSError: No such file or directory: '[virtual environment]/..local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/[package-name]-0.1-py2.7.egg'

Tags: pip, setup.py, pypi

I am creating an PYPI application(to install using pip). I built it using command "python setup.py build" and installed in local machine(inside virtual environment. using [ubuntu 12.4]). whenever I try to UN-install using "pip uninstall " it gives the following error.

**Message displayed while installing it**

> Copying fantain_DBC-0.1-py2.7.egg to /home/kavin/.virtualenvs/pavan_pkg/lib/python2.7/site-packages
>   Adding fantain-DBC 0.1 to easy-install.pth file
>   Installed /home/kavin/.virtualenvs/pavan_pkg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fantain_DBC-0.1-py2.7.egg
>   Processing dependencies for fantain-DBC==0.1
>   Finished processing dependencies for fantain-DBC==0.1
>   Blockquote

**Error message while uninstalling**

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/kavin/.virtualenvs/pavan_pkg/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fantain_DBC-0.1-py2.7.egg'
```

Comment: May be the app was installed in `.../pavan_pkg/lib/python2.7/...` and you try to uninstall from `.../pavan_pkg/local/lib/python2.7/...` ?